# Google Chrome not rendering PDF colours properly

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, rendering

When these [PDFs](http://www.novum.ie/images/uploads/downloads/Novum-France.pdf) are opened in browser in Google Chrome the colours are changed drastically, but when opened in another browser or opened in Preview on Mac the colours go back to normal.

It also doesnt occur in some [other languages](http://www.novum.ie/images/uploads/downloads/Novum_USA_Brochure_Small.pdf).

You can see in the screenshot below what it should display (top) and what it is displaying (bottom).

[image: Comparison Screenshots]

Comment: Unless you wrote Chrome or Preview, this doesn't seem to be a programming-related question.

Answer (score 0):

The first page consists of a single large JPEG2000 compressed image: 8 bit indexed color, 1276 x 1790 pixels.

A quick look at [a comparison of browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers) shows Chrome does not support JPEG2000 (officially at least, since you still got to see *something*).

There seem to be some plugins that add JPEG2000 support to Chrome, but

1. that is a *local* solution, it does not fix the issue for all users; and
2. Chrome uses its own internal PDF renderer, so it might not work "inside" PDFs.